# Plural or singular verb with this subject

Tags: subjects

Funding and financial management sometimes (remains or remain) difficult.

Can you please tell me wich one is correct and why?

Comment: "John and Bill goes fishing" or "John and Bill go fishing"?

Comment: Ignore the unhelpful – no, worse: misleading – comment above. I'd use 'bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast' but 'bacon and eggs have both become very expensive over the last two years'. Are you seeing 'Funding and financial management' as two separate elements or a composite field?